# React Component object value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In Javascript, there is Object value mapping like this:

```js
const tmpMapping = {
  component: import('src/views/tmp.js'),
}
```

Is it possible? Or the other ways to mapping React component object value import?

Comment: I don't think that will work. What is exported from `tmp.js`? Why not just something like `import component from '/views/tmp.js';` and then `const tempMapping = { component };`? What exactly are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: This might be a bit of an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Perhaps you should ask about/describe the issue or problem you are trying to solve instead of asking about this solution you are trying that doesn't appear to be correct or doable. See [how to ask](/help/how-to-ask) for other tips to improve the quality of your post to get it to a more answerable state.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm trying to make some program dynamic menu and program mapping. "When developing a specific screen within the program and deploying it, I want to insert a JavaScript file, register it with the menu and program, and then, by referencing the URL from the database, display the corresponding screen. Currently, I am facing difficulties due to the shortcomings in my JavaScript. I am looking for a way to dynamically create a method for registering the program in the routes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to map a React component to an object, you can do it by importing the React component first.

```
import TmpComponent from 'src/views/tmp.js';

const tmpMapping = {
    Component: TmpComponent
}

// Usage example
<tmpMapping.Component />
```

Comment: I want to dynamic import. any other ways?

Comment: @seotaejun Why do you want to have dynamic import? Could you tell me what you are trying to do?